# How to model DDD business objects structures in Akka.Net?

Tags: akka.net

For an imagined hierarchy modeled as:

```
Tenancy

    TenancyUser

        TenancyUserAccounts

            TenancyUserAccount

                TenancyUserAccountItems

                    TenancyUserAccountAccountItem
```

Or maybe the hierarchy be more simply realised as:

```
Tenancy

    TenancyUser

        TenancyUserAccount

            TenancyUserAccountAccountItem
```

How would I go about representing this in code as a hierarchical structure of Actors in Akka.net?

I'm coming from a DDD background and I'm sure it's a straightforward leap to make once I get my head around it. Actually, it feels a bit embarrassing to be asking such a fundamentally simple question but there you go. New shiny and all that.

Thanks!
R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to say, since DDD requires at least some level of expertise over domain, that is modeled. In general usually you map aggregate root instances to actors in 1-1 fashion i.e. assuming that your `TenancyUser` is an aggregate root, it's represented by exactly one stateful actor incarnation at the time. All entities below it's hierarchy are not actors, just usual objects.

There is no sense in mapping each domain entity to separate actor, since accordingly to DDD principles, all operations over aggregate-dependent entities should be done through aggregate roots themselfs.